# Using C# Windows 10 is it possible to tell if the video/camera is currently in use by any app?

Tags: c#, windows, video, camera

I would like to build a windows forms app, or console app that can "ping" the camera to see if it's being used to capture images/video. Is this possible? An example would be that if I'm in a goto-meeting and sharing my camera i could flip a flag in an app.

If so could you share a snippet?

Answer (score -1):

I do not have a specific snippet but maybe I can help you with how I would approach this problem. One way would be to find out what Physical Device Object Name your webcam has. Every process using this holds this name, so if you check that you can see whether any other process uses.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I have a feeling this may be error prone, and also knowing if there's an active stream or not may be tough. I'm HOPING there's some API or stream somewhere that tells if it's ACTUALLY "transmitting" versus just plugged in.